# Ruby on Rails URL Homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, uri

I'm very new to ROR and very impressed so far, its extremely fast and structured well. I've been taught to use the command.

```
rails generate controller Welcome index
```

I understand it so far as.. create me a non-db-driven page in a sub-directory.. so the above would be:

```
localhost:3000/welcome/index
```

but what if I want my domain www.something.com (localhost:3000) to be the homepage?

As in (for a normal site) putting a index.html in the root.

is this possible, is there a reason I cant find the answer anywhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: set root route `root to: 'welcome#index'` in `config/routes.rb`

Comment: I don't think it deserves an upvote, but upvoted to negativate the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the index action of the welcome controller the homepage:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'welcome#index'
```

See the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.x

To set homepage add following line to the end of the routes.rb file:

```
 root :to => "welcome#index"
```

and delete public/index.html.erb.

Please also note that welcome#index corresponds to index action in a WelcomeController

Rails 4

```
 root 'welcome#index'
```